# Having trouble with web scraping using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having hard time web scraping this web page [top-programming-guru](https://noonies.tech/award/top-programming-guru).
I was looking to have retrieve  a list of all the youtube channels listed in the page.
I'm using `BeautifulSoup`, I took a look at source code of page, Then and try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://noonies.tech/award/top-programming-guru'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

resluts = soup.find_all('div', class_='sc-jhAzac dldLgq')
resluts
```

But I always get an empty list.
Any ideas how to do this correctly?

this the tag I was looking for

```
<div class="sc-jhAzac dldLgq">
 <p>
  
  <em>And the winner is...</em>
 </p>
<div class="sc-gZMcBi kTYIfA">
 <div class="nomination-info">
  <h3><i class="fad fa-trophy"></i><a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/programmingwithmosh/videos" target="_blank">Programming with Mosh</a></h3>
```

Comment: I don't see anything with that class in that page.

Comment: I was look to this tag  <div class="sc-jhAzac dldLgq"><p><em>And the winner is...</em></p><div class="sc-gZMcBi kTYIfA"><div class="nomination-info"><h3><i class="fad fa-trophy"></i><a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/programmingwithmosh/videos" target="_blank">Programming with Mosh</a></h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is dynamically loaded. Use selenium or similar to allow javascript to load then scrape.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
url = 'https://noonies.tech/award/top-programming-guru'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find_all(href=re.compile('youtube.com'))
```

Outputs a list of href with youtube.com in it. You may have to clean up the list if it captures youtube.com links you don't want or go back to your class search.

```
[<a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/programmingwithmosh/videos" target="_blank">Programming with Mosh</a>,
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/TechGuyWeb" target="_blank">Traversy Media</a>,
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5" target="_blank">Corey Schafer</a>,
 <a href="https://m.youtube.com/channel/UC4JX40jDee_tINbkjycV4Sg" target="_blank">Tech With Tim</a>,
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/krishnaik06/playlists" target="_blank">Krish Naik</a>,
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ" target="_blank">freeCodeCamp.org</a>,
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/HiteshChoudharydotcom" target="_blank">Hitesh Choudhary</a>,
 <a href="https://m.youtube.com/cleverprogrammer?uid=qrILQNl5Ed9Dz6CGMyvMTQ" target="_blank">Clever Programmer</a>,
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/CalebTheVideoMaker2" target="_blank">Caleb Curry</a>,....
```